# How to format the references heading when using multiple bibliographies

Tags: sectioning, biblatex, formatting, subdividing

I have what I hope is a simple question. I finally figured out how to get the multiple bibliographies to work (mostly) like I want it. The one additional formatting thing I would like is to make the "References" heading centered upon the page. What I am getting now is the heading "References" flush left.

Here is my code:

```
{\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=none,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{simple_example.bib}

\title{Here is the title.}
\author{ John S. Doe }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\include{Chapter01}
\printbibliography[section=1,heading=References]
\include{Chapter02}
\printbibliography[section=2,heading=References]
\end{document}
```

Code for Chapter01.tex

```
\chapter{This is Chapter 01}
\begin{refsection}
Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{goossens93}.
Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{knuth79}.
\end{refsection}'
```

Code for Chapter02.tex

```
\chapter{This is Chapter 02}
\begin{refsection}
 Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{knuth79}. 
 Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{greenwade93,knuth79}.    
\end{refsection}
```

And code for the bib file:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.6.
% Encoding: ISO8859_1
@book{goossens93,
author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
title = "The Latex Companion A",
year = "1993",
publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@article{greenwade93,
author = "George D. Greenwade",
title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
year = "1993",
journal = "TUGBoat",
volume = "14",
number = "3",
pages = "342--351",
url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
author = "Donald E. Knuth",
title = "Tex and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
year = "1979",
publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
address = "Stanford"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example code is not consistent: you use `article` as the document class and then use `\chapter` in the subsidiary files.

Anyway, you can use `\defbibheading` to format the bibliography headings; the syntax is

```
\defbibheading{<name>}[<title>]{<code>}
```

where `<name>` is the identifier to be used in the `heading` option of `\printbibliography` and `<code>` should be some LaTeX code to generate the heading; for further details, see Section **3.5.7 Bibliography Headings and Environments** of the `biblatex` manual.

A little example producing the title "References" centered, in the style used by `\chapter*` and taking care of the running headings:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{simpleexample.bib}
@book{goossens93,
author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
title = "The {LaTeX} {C}ompanion",
year = "1993",
publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@article{greenwade93,
author = "George D. Greenwade",
title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
year = "1993",
journal = "TUGBoat",
volume = "14",
number = "3",
pages = "342--351",
url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
author = "Donald E. Knuth",
title = "{TeX} and {M}etafont, {N}ew {D}irections in {T}ypesetting",
year = "1979",
publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
address = "Stanford"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=none,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{simpleexample.bib}

\defbibheading{references}[\refname]{\chapter*{\centering#1}
   \markboth{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is Chapter 01}
\begin{refsection}
Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{goossens93}.
Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{knuth79}.
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[section=1,heading=references]

\chapter{This is Chapter 02}
\begin{refsection}
 Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{knuth79}. 
 Blah, blah, blah, ba-blah \cite{greenwade93,knuth79}.    
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[section=2,heading=references]

\end{document}
```