# Changing "Bibliography" title with biblatex - within the document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

The answer to [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr) describes very nicely how to change the title of the bibliography in the preamble when using biblatex.
My problem:

I am printing multiple bibliographies and want to have different title for each of them. My file looks something like this:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[
    style=authortitle-dw, 
    backref=true,
    idembib=true,
    firstfull=true,
    backrefstyle=two+,
    hyperref=true,
    isbn=false,
    backend=biber,
    citereset=chapter,
    bibencoding=utf8
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\addbibresource{predigten.bib}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}
\addbibresource{lexika.bib}
\addbibresource{unverquellen.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
      \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=literatur, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{quellen.bib}
      \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=quellen, append]
    }
    \map{
        \perdatasource{unverquellen.bib}
        \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=unverquellen, append]
    }
    \map{
        \perdatasource{predigten.bib}
        \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=predigten, append]
    }
    \map{
        \perdatasource{lexika.bib}
        \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=lexika, append]
    }
  }
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    bibliography = {Literaturverzeichnis},
    references = {Literaturverzeichnis}
}   
\printbibliography[keyword=literatur]
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    bibliography = {Quellenverzeichnis},
    references = {Quellenverzeichnis}
}
\printbibliography[keyword=quellen]
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    bibliography = {Verzeichnis der unveroffentlichten Quellen},
    references = {Verzeichnis der unveroffentlichten Quellen}
}
\printbibliography[keyword=unverquellen]
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    bibliography = {Predigtverzeichnis},
    references = {Predigtverzeichnis}
}
\printbibliography[keyword=predigten]
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    bibliography = {Lexika},
    references = {Lexika}
}
\printbibliography[keyword=lexika]
\end{document}
```

it tells me `\DefineBibliographyStrings` can only be called in the preamble. Does anyone have a solution

Comment: Why aren't you using `\defbibheading{<name>}{<code>}` and then `\printbibliography[heading=<name>]`?  You can define as many headings as you want....

Comment: See `§ 3.6.8, p.80` of the documentation.

Comment: `\printbibliography[title=Mein Titel]`

Comment: See also [How to format the references heading when using multiple bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32201/35864), [Structuring the bibliography by headings and subheadings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106292/35864) and [How to format bibliography titles as section, subsection, and subsubsection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134958/35864).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `title`-key to set a specific header:

```
\printbibliography[title=Mein Titel]
```

More complicated solutions are only needed if they should be able to adapt to more then one language or something similar..

Comment: It changes the title from "Bibliography" to our desired name mentioned in "title" string. But this section is not showing now in table of contents.  Do you know how to accomplish this ? My code was `\printbibliography[title=References]
\label{bib:mybiblio}`

Comment: What if I don't want any title? Also, I don't want the line for the title to be empty.

Comment: @H.R. Don't ask such questions in comments. Ask a new question together with a suitable minimal example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Your are right but I thought that it is closely related to this question and your answer. :) It seems `\printbibliography[heading=none]` does the job.

Comment: @H.R. It doesn't matter if it is related or not. By asking your question in a comment of an old answer you are actually trying to force me -- and me alone -- to solve your problem. That is not ok. I'm not your personal support.